# How do you check time in a DB to todays date?

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to write a conditional that would check a date in a table. If the date in the table is the same as todays date, it would ignore. If not it wouldn't break.

```
if(strtotime($row['timefield']) == (date(Y-m-d)){

break 1;
}
```

^ This doesn't work but it's sort of what I am trying to do. Thoughts?

Comment: if the entity exists and the date is the same as todays date, it shouldn't be inserted again. That's what break is for.

Comment: The field is a DATETIME.

Comment: That's what primary keys are used for. Don't re-invent the wheel - use good DB design ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can just do it on the database side if your database is using the local time/date.

(Assuming MySQL, and `timefield` is a date type):

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN timefield = CURDATE()
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    AS is_today
```

If `timefield` is datetime then:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN DATE(timefield) = CURDATE()
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    AS is_today
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `timefield` is of `DATE` type:

```
if (strtotime($row['timefield']) != date('Y-m-d')){
    // Do insert
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the formatting of your datetime. Instead compere something that is much for comparable and rigid, like unix timestamp.

So basically what NullPointer just said... Damn that was quick :D